# Why is the L dynamoDB attribute type not included in Terraform's AWS dynamoDB attribute def?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In the Terraform AWS provider source code, https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/aws/resource_aws_dynamodb_table.go#L116-L118, DynamoDB B, N, and S data attribute types are allowed.

Yet, I need to create an L attribute field (array of type string), which the AWS dynamoDB docs list as an allowed field type, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html.

Why does terraform not allow this?

Answer (score 4):

In Terraform you define the attributes you need to use as keys (partition, sort, local index, global index) and as the name implies, they should be primitives.
So for things to use as keys having String, Number, and Binary would be enough and useful. It's also worth mentioning that it's not a good idea to have a key of type object (complex object) beside the fact that isn't supported by the AWS event if you try to do it using the console.

If one attribute of your data is a map/array/etc. then you don't have to define that field/attribute in Terraform because it's NoSQL table

Answer (score 3):

My mistake, the attribute just needs to declare the underlying type (Binary, Number, or String), not how the type is used (single value vs array).

Comment: I still don't understand. What if your list would consist of objects?

Comment: Then it's not a key :) @Lightheaded